# Problems printing List of Figures on TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm trying to print the `List of Figures` on the TOC.

For that I'm using this:

```
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{My Custom Name} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
```

But when I compile, I see two records, the first `My Custom Name` and the second `List of Figures` with the same number of page. I'd like that only appear `My custom Name`

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

It's only a guess, but I assume that something like `tocbibind` is loaded, adding the `\listoffigures` automatically to the ToC.

In any case, the `\addcontentsline` is wrong in such a setup, since it doubles the occurence of the `List of Figures` (or the custom title then)

```
\documentclass{book}%

\usepackage{tocbibind}%


\usepackage{blindtext}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{My Custom Name}%
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}% 
\listoffigures


\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` will avoid the abomination of adding the table of contents to the table of contents.

Comment: If I use `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` I can't see `\lstlistoflistings`

Comment: @Joan: I asked you about a MWE, but so far, you added none  -- we can't know about `\lstlistoflistings` if we don't get information about it's usage!